# Barra de Rolagem Horizontal, selectOneMenu - PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee, cdi, horizontal

Bom Dia, Estou desenvolvendo um projeto acadêmico utilizando JAVA EE, JSF, PrimeFaces, CDI, Hibernete entre outras tecnologias...

O layout é responsivo e estou usando PanelGrid para organizar os componeres do formulário

A situação é.. selectOneMenu contem textos horizontais muito grandes, maiores que o espaço disponível para seleção queria uma barra de rolagem, como no exemplo:

```
------------------------
|Selecione         | v |
------------------------
|Texto.................|
|Texto.................|
|Texto.................|
|Texto.................|
|Texto.................|
|Texto.................|
________________________
|Barra de Rolagem    <>|
------------------------
```

Tenho muito pouco contato com desenvolvimento Web, visto que faz apanas alguns dias que comecei a desenvolver.

Não consegui definir tamanho para o componente pois ele esta em um grid Responsivo..

Dese de já agradeço a atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que você faça alguns testes com o CSS do primefaces. Consegui alguns resultados semelhantes aqui usando as classes `ui-selectonemenu-items` e `ui-selectonemenu-items`. Para um teste simples, acrescente isso no seu XHTML:

```
<style>
    .ui-selectonemenu-items {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ui-selectonemenu-item {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Como você disse que é iniciante, sugiro também dar uma lida em http://johnylab.net/?id=119 para saber como testar o CSS no seu próprio navegador.